# elpy - This feature requires the ‘jedi‘ package to be installed

Tags: elpy, jedi

I am getting following error when I do `M-x elpy-goto-definition`, even though I have installed `jedi`. I have followed following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29934511/2402577) and [this one.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19194/18414)

Error message: `This feature requires the ‘jedi‘ package to be installed.`

---

My configuration as follows:

```
(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :init
  (elpy-enable))

(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")

;;;;;;; Standard Jedi.el setting
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:ac-setup)
(setq jedi:setup-keys t)                      ; optional
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)                 ; optional
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook (lambda () (highlight-indentation-mode -1)))
```

**[Q]** How could I combine `elpy` and `jedi`?

Comment: What is the output of M-x elpy-config? That should tell you if it’s having a problem accessing any components like Jedi.

Comment: Don't know if that is the issue, but you try to `(elpy-enable)` before `elpy` is loaded. Change `:init` to `:config` [Read at the manual about the function of both keywords](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/).

Comment: elpy-config => https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/a1e0720a337a8ceb1ccf364edd36afdf @AndrewE

Comment: I have done it but still I am getting the same error @jue

Comment: You might have to tell it where your Jedi binary is if it isn’t on your PATH. Look for a variable named elpy-Jedi-executable or something similar and customize it to be the path to the Jedi executable.

Comment: `jediepcserver.py` exists under `~/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-0.2.8`

Comment: @alper what happens when you click “[install jedi]” on the elpy-config screen?

Comment: That comment I made about Jedi executable was wrong btw, sorry. I was thinking of flycheck I think.

Comment: I get following output: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/bdb9b1fc063393195d07bbc53a14c5f8   // but still I am having the same error

Comment: Can you restart emacs and run elpy config again to see if it is detecting the new Jedi install?

Comment: @alper sorry can't help, I don't use elpy nor jedi.

Comment: Actually when I wait little bit it is solved. It takes around few minutes to `jedi server` to be detected by `emacs`, is it normal?

Comment: I have changed `:init` to `:config` should I make any additional change as well? Eventually `jedi` loads but it takes some time@jue