# How to improve ‘jedi‘ package's load time

Tags: performance, load, jedi

When I try to use [jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/installation.html) package I get following message in the minibuffer.

```
This feature requires the ‘jedi‘ package to be installed. Please check ‘elpy-config‘ for more information.
```

---

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 26.3
Elpy..............: 1.34.0
Virtualenv........: venv (/home/alper/venv)
Interactive Python: python3 3.7.5 (/home/alper/venv/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/alper/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python 3.7.5 (/home/alper/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python)
 Jedi.............: 0.17.2
 Rope.............: 0.16.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.3 (1.5.4 available)
 Yapf.............: 0.29.0 (0.30.0 available)
 Black............: 19.10b0 (20.8b1 available)
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/alper/venv/bin/flake8)
```

---

After few minutes it starts working or when I restart `emacs` there are some cases that it starts working right way. So its behavior is random for its load time to start.

**=>** Is there anything I can do to prevent this error to force `jedi` to start right away? or is this a normal behavior of `jedi`?

Please note that I had similiar question ([elpy - This feature requires the ‘jedi‘ package to be installed](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/55836/18414)), but it was not related to `jedi` package's load time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While switching configurations I've came across this issue yet again and I believe I have a workaround for this if you're still interested.

The steps I do to reproduce:

- start fresh emacs,
- `venv-workon` to activate a virtualenv,
- open a python buffer,
- try `elpy-goto-definition`, receive the same error message you did.
- (`elpy-config` confirms everything is ok)

Now, I was under the impression that `elpy-goto-definition` will just utilize the same mechanism as `xref-find-definitions`, but apparently that's not exactly the case. If I try to run the latter, something else happens the first time around (which might be triggering the connection to rpc) and I get a different error message. But the second time around it is already connected and I can use it at will.

This is assuming that `xref-backend-functions` includes `elpy-xref-backend`.

Please let me know if this solves the issue and if you have dug deeper to explain the reasoning behind the bug.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. What changes should I do to my `init.el` file to achieve your workaround?

Comment: With your current config try calling `xref-find-defiitions` twice right after startup and let me know if the second call gives you the expected result.