# How to restart elpy if it is not launch?

Tags: python, elpy

I am working with `python` using `Emacs 26.3`. My goal is to jump to definition of the function and jump back, for that I am using https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump, which runs `elpy-goto-definition` on the background.

I am starting emacs on startup using [crontab](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm) using `(&>/dev/null emacsclient -t -q &)`. On that case, `elpy-goto-definition` never works. I have to restart emacs. But after the restart, it takes around 30 seconds for `elpy` to launch, sometimes it does not launch (I do not know why).

- What may be the main reason that let `elpy-goto-definition` to fail. Can I force `elpy-goto-definition` to work if it fails? or restart `elpy` within `emacs` if possible?

My setup:

```
(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook (lambda () (highlight-indentation-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'xref-backend-functions #'dumb-jump-xref-activate)

;; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19194/18414
(defun goto-def-or-rgrep ()
  "Go to definition of thing at point or do an rgrep in project if that fails"
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil (elpy-goto-definition)
    (error (elpy-rgrep-symbol (thing-at-point 'symbol)))))

(global-set-key "\C-x\C-j" 'goto-def-or-rgrep)
```

Comment: To jump to a definition I simply use `M-.`and to jump back `M-,` 
I have nothing special in my init file.
What you do seems very complicated to me.
Sorry if I misunderstand your problem.

Comment: Which function does `M-.` run in the background?

Comment: `M-,` runs the command xref-pop-marker-stack (found in global-map),
which is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘xref.el’.

It is bound to `M-*`, `M-,`, <menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <xref-pop>.

`(xref-pop-marker-stack)`

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 25.1.

Pop back to where `M-.` was last invoked.

Comment: `M-.` runs the command xref-find-definitions (found in global-map),
which is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘xref.el’. It is bound to `M-.`, <menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <xref-find-def>.
(xref-find-definitions IDENTIFIER)
Find the definition of the identifier at point. With prefix argument or when there’s no identifier at point, prompt for it.If sufficient information is available to determine a unique
definition for IDENTIFIER, display it in the selected window.
Otherwise, display the list of the possible definitions in a buffer where the user can select from the list.

Comment: `xref-find-definitions` returns no definition found even the function is defined

Comment: After bisecting my init file I have the same problem if I remove this line ` '(elpy-rpc-virtualenv-path "~/.virtualenvs/python3.8")` I'll give you an extract of my init file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To jump to a definition I simply use `M-.`and to jump back `M-,`
In my init file I have that:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.

 '(elpy-modules
   (quote
    (elpy-module-company elpy-module-eldoc elpy-module-pyvenv elpy-module-highlight-indentation elpy-module-yasnippet elpy-module-django elpy-module-sane-defaults)))
 '(elpy-rpc-python-command "python3")
 '(elpy-rpc-virtualenv-path "~/.virtualenvs/python3.8")
)
```

In the menu bar > Elpy > Configure

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 27.1
Elpy..............: 1.35.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: python 2.7.16 (/usr/bin/python)
RPC virtualenv....: python3.8 (/Users/raoul/.virtualenvs/python3.8)
 Python...........: python3 3.8.1 (/Users/raoul/.virtualenvs/python3.8/bin/python3)
 Jedi.............: 0.16.0 (0.18.0 available)
 Rope.............: Not found (0.18.0 available)
 Autopep8.........: 1.5 (1.5.5 available)
 Yapf.............: 0.29.0 (0.30.0 available)
 Black............: 19.10b0 (20.8b1 available)
Syntax checker....: Not found (flake8)
```